# translate from pyrotch to tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch

What does this line of code in PyTorch do?

```
normA = A.mul(A).sum(dim=1).sum(dim=1).sqrt()
Y = A.div(normA.view(batchSize, 1, 1).expand_as(A))
```

Normally it should be a second term like this:

```
torch.div(input, value, out=None) → Tensor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear because you didn't mention what is the shape of tensor `A` and what is `normA`. But I guess the following:

- `A` is a tensor of shape `(batchSize, X, Y)`
- `normA` is a tensor of norms of all batch elements of `A` and its' shape is `(batchSize)`.

So, you normalize the tensor `A` with the following statement.

```
A.div(normA.view(batchSize, 1, 1).expand_as(A))
```

Where, `normA.view(batchSize, 1, 1).expand_as(A)` is first converted into a tensor of shape `(batchSize, X, Y)` and then you divide `A` by the resulting tensor.

An example (created from my guess):

```
batchSize = 8

A = torch.randn(batchSize, 5, 5)
normA = A.norm(dim=-1).norm(dim=-1)
print(normA.size()) # torch.Size([8])

normA = normA.view(batchSize, 1, 1).expand_as(A)
print(normA.size()) # torch.Size([8, 5, 5])

A = A.div(normA)
```

Comment: can you show me how to write it in tensorflow notation please